# Visual Studio Preprocessor - access compiler flags

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am currently converting a Qt project from being .pro file based to Visual Studio based.

In the original .pro file I have used the following

```
LIBSTR = '\\"$${LIBS}\\"'
DEFINES += LIBRARIES=\"$${LIBSTR}\"
```

Which allows me to see what libraries were used in my application.

I would like to replicate this in Visual Studio but cannot see how to do this.

Comment: Port to QBS rather than Visual Studio then. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the `configure.h` to the project

```
#pragma once
#define LIBRARIES TEXT("")
```

2) Add `$${LIBS}` to the `Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` section.

3) Add to the `Project properties -> Build Events -> Pre-Build Event` a script like:

```
cscript /nologo configure.js $(ProjectPath) $(ConfigurationName) $(PlatformName)
```

configure.js:

```
var proj = WScript.Arguments(0);
var conf = WScript.Arguments(1);
var platf = WScript.Arguments(2);
var configFile = "configure.h";

try {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject("msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
    doc.async = false;
    doc.resolveExternals = false;
    doc.validateOnParse = false;
    doc.load(proj);

    var node = doc.selectSingleNode("//Configuration[@Name=\""+conf+"|"+platf+"\"]/Tool[@Name=\"VCLinkerTool\"]");
    var attr = node.attributes.getNamedItem("AdditionalDependencies");
    var libStr = attr ? attr.value : "";

    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var aFile = fso.GetFile(".\\" + configFile);
    var fStream = aFile.OpenAsTextStream(1);

    var re = new RegExp("^\\s*#\\s*define\\s+LIBRARIES\\s+");
    var done = false;
    var text = "";
    while (!fStream.AtEndOfStream) {
        var aStr = fStream.ReadLine();
        if (!done && re.test(aStr)) {
            aStr = "#define LIBRARIES TEXT(\"" + libStr.replace(/(\\|")/g, "\\$1") + "\")";
            done = true;
        }
        text += aStr + "\n";
    }
    fStream.Close();

    fStream = aFile.OpenAsTextStream(2);
    fStream.Write(text);
    fStream.Close();
} catch (e) {
    WScript.Echo("Error:");
    WScript.Echo(e.description);
    WScript.Quit(1);
}

WScript.Echo("Done");
WScript.Quit(0);
```

Then after you'll start the build the `configure.h` file will be updated and `LIBRARIES` will contain all libs you defined for the current build configuration and platform.